# Try/Except if function is false

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have a function which works out whether or not the file is in a n x n square matrix i.e. 3x3 or 4x4. Now if I call the function it works fine; it says whether or not it is a nxn square.

My problem is I want to use an exception, if the function returns a False value, then it wont load the text file but give a error saying to ensure the file has a nxn grid.
So for example if I have the grid stored in a text file and I try to load it with python code; the program should keep looping until the file is in the correct format. I wasn't sure if there was an exception for a function boolean

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
J
```

Currently I have

```
def grid(n):
    rows = len(n)
    for row in n:
        if len(row) != rows:
            return False
```

Similar to how the file open works; if it doesn't exist (FileNotFoundError) then it'll keep looping until it finds the input file name

Comment: Every time an exception is raised, it is because some test was False.  What you want is probably `ValueError`, because you have the right type, but the wrong value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Simply raise an appropriate exception if `square(d)` returns `False`.

```
#Return True if sq is square, False otherwise
def square(sq):
    rows = len(sq)
    return all(len(row) == rows for row in sq)

def loaddata():
    while True:
        try:
            filename = input("Enter the name of the file to open: ") + ".txt"
            with open(filename, "r") as f:
                d = []
                for line in f:
                    splitLine = line.split()
                    d.append(splitLine)

            if not square(d):
                raise ValueError

            break

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File name does not exist; please try again")
        except ValueError:
            print("The format is incorrect")

    for line in d:
        print("".join(line))
```

We reset `d` to `[]` each time through the loop in case we need to get rid of the contents of a previous file that isn't square.

Comment: This works IF the format is incorrect. If i make the format a correct nxn grid in the text file; it still says the format is incorrect. Any reason why? And why did you have to move the list?

Comment: @Xrin Sorry. I forgot to post my new version of `square`. Give me a minute.

Comment: Thank you; in fact my original square function works also; however for some reason it only works if my text file has a tab spacing between each letter? Its strange. If i put them together i.e. ABC then it doesnt work properly. But its good to have multiple methods

Comment: @Xrin: You should only be doing `splitLine = line.split();d.append(splitLine)` if there's whitespace between the letters. Otherwise, just do  `d.append(line.strip())`; the `.strip` gets rid of trailing whitespace on each line, in particular it gets rid of the newline.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing handing the exception (the "except" statement) with raising one. What you should do in square is raise an exception instead of returning false and then handle it in your main program:

```
def square(sq):
    rows = len(sq)
    for row in sq:
        if len(row) != rows:
            raise ValueError("the format is incorrect") 


def loaddata():
    while True:
        try:
            filename=input("Enter the name of the file to open: ") + ".txt"
            with open(filename,"r") as f:
                for line in f:
                    splitLine=line.split()
                    d.append(splitLine)
                break
            square(d)

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File name does not exist; please try again")     

        except ValueError:
                print("The format is incorrect")

    for line in d:
        print("".join(line))   
    return
```

Comment: If this still doesn't work (i.e. Still loading the file) Does that mean the code is incorrect or my function isn't working properly? Because atm; its still not raising the error